# Extending a Worksheetformula through VBA without writing only the value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My problem is the following:
I have a template which I populate using VBA. I enter time values of employees when they come and go. At the bottom of the table there is a formula in the template that sums up the hours worked.

A typical set looks like this...

```
A1: 08:00
A2: 12:00
A3: 13:00
A4: 17:00
A5: =(A1-A2)+(A3-A4)
```

If an employee has worked an additional time block, let's say from 18:00-22:00, then i need to add that into the template. I do this by inserting two rows below A4 and copying the formating from the lines above. All of this I do with VBA. So the worksheet now looks like this:

```
A1: 08:00
A2: 12:00
A3: 13:00
A4: 17:00
A5: 18:00
A6: 22:00
A7: =(A1-A2)+(A3-A4)
```

My problem is that I need to adjust the formula in A7, and it absolutely NEEDS TO BE A FORMULA, because the employee should be able to enter values in the prepopulated template after I creat it.

I'm at a loss how to do this.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier if you used two columns for the input and a third for the formula - you can then just total the formula in the third column.

Comment: Hi Rory, if I had been able to change the format at all, it would have been easier, but the format is givne and I can't change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data are in **pairs** of values in a single column, you can simply create the proper formula and place it at the bottom of the column:

```
Sub FormulaMaker()
    Dim N As Long, sForm As String, sLittle As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N - 1 Step 2
        sLittle = "(A" & i & "-A" & i + 1 & ")"
        If sForm = "" Then
            sForm = "=" & sLittle
        Else
            sForm = sForm & "+" & sLittle
        End If
    Next i
    Cells(N + 1, "A").Formula = sForm
End Sub
```

Also you may want to use *(A2-A1)* rather than *(A1-A2)*

Comment: I was working on another topic when I started to think of a similar solution. I even started implementing it, but your's is a more elegant version! Thanks so much!

Comment: This answer also taught me that I can reference a column as "A" when using Cells(). Cool!